# Trying to understand why simple jsonix unmarshalling is failing

Tags: jsonix

I am new to jsonix and interested mostly in using it to unmarshall xml data. I wrote a very basic test example but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

```
var MyModule = {
    name: 'MyModule',
    typeInfos: [{
        type: 'classInfo',
        localName: 'AnyElementType',
        propertyInfos: [{
            type: 'anyElement',
            allowDom: true,
            allowTypedObject:true,
            name: 'any',
            collection: false
        }]
    }],
    elementInfos: [{
        elementName: 'sos:Capabilities',
        typeInfo: 'MyModule.AnyElementType'
    }]
  };

  var context = new Jsonix.Context([MyModule], {namespacePrefixes:  {'http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0':'sos'}});
  var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
  var data = unmarshaller.unmarshalString('<sos:Capabilities version=\"2.0.0\">hello</sos:Capabilities>');
  return data;
```

I hardcoded a single simple element that has a namespace and contains 'hello' for the test xml. I was interested in the 'any element mapping' for generic unmarshalling. I feel like I have the namespace configured appropriately etc when creating the context yet I keep getting the following error:
Element [sos:Capabilities] could not be unmarshalled as is not known in this context and the property does not allow DOM content. Thoughts? and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

There are two issues here.

First, you're missing `xmlns:sos="http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0"` in your XML.

Second, currently you'll need to define the element name as an object with `namespaceURI` and `localPart`. If you just use string, Jsonix will use `defaultElementNamespaceURI` (which is not defined here). The `namespacePrefixes` option is currently not applied in `elementInfos`. This would be a fine feature, please [file an issue](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/issues) if you want this.

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lexi/xap3f7jz/) with you module.

```
var MyModule = {
  name: 'MyModule',
  typeInfos: [{
    type: 'classInfo',
    localName: 'AnyElementType',
    propertyInfos: [{
      type: 'anyElement',
      allowDom: true,
      allowTypedObject: true,
      name: 'any',
      collection: false
    }]
  }],
  elementInfos: [{
    elementName: {
      namespaceURI: 'http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0',
      localPart: 'Capabilities'
    },
    // 'sos:Capabilities',
    typeInfo: 'MyModule.AnyElementType'
  }]
};

var context = new Jsonix.Context([MyModule], {
  namespacePrefixes: {
    'http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0': 'sos'
  }
});
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
var data = unmarshaller.unmarshalString('<sos:Capabilities version=\"2.0.0\" xmlns:sos=\"http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0\">hello</sos:Capabilities>');
console.log(data);
```