# Why jsonix unmarshalling fails for artificial URIs

Tags: amazon-mws, jsonix

In my attempt to use a schema file that I created: [ListMatchingProductsResponse.xsd](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-listmatchingproductsresponse-xsd), I run into an error similar to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033419/trying-to-understand-why-simple-jsonix-unmarshalling-is-failing) but I don't think that the underlying fix is that same.

When I try to parse a [sample response](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-sample-response-xml):

```
var ListMatchingProductsResponse = require('/mappings/ListMatchingProductsResponse').ListMatchingProductsResponse;
var Jsonix = require('jsonix').Jsonix;
var context = new Jsonix.Context([ListMatchingProductsResponse]);
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.unmarshalFile('sample-response.xml',
  function (unmarshalled) {
    console.log('unmarshalled:', unmarshalled);
  });
});
```

I end up with:

```
Uncaught Error:
  Element [{http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01}ListMatchingProductsResponse]
  could not be unmarshalled as is not known in this context
  and the property does not allow DOM content.
```

### My Suspicions:

I've tried various unintelligent hacks thus far but just don't understand what the problem here is. Hoping that someone with a better eagle-eye view and understanding can help.

What sticks out most clearly for me is that the [sample response](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-sample-response-xml-L2)

1. ties `ListMatchingProductsResponse` with the `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01` namespace
2. whereas my schema ties it to the artificial `http://localhost:8000/ListMatchingProductsResponse.xsd` namespace because I'm the one creating the schema and defining `ListMatchingProductsResponse` as a `complexType`.

Here's an excerpt from my [mappings/ListMatchingProductsResponse.js](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-listmatchingproductsresponse-js-L518) file which is generated after running: `java -jar node_modules/jsonix/lib/jsonix-schema-compiler-full.jar -d mappings -p ListMatchingProductsResponse cache/xsd/localhost_8000/ListMatchingProductsResponse.xsd`

```
{
    localName: 'ListMatchingProductsResponse',
    typeName: {
      namespaceURI: 'http:\/\/localhost:8000\/ListMatchingProductsResponse.xsd',
      localPart: 'ListMatchingProductsResponse'
},
```

### My attempts at trial & error:

I really did not want to change the response because I really have no control over it but I fiddled with it to see if things could be different by fixing the namespace to be my artificial one but that still resulted in the same error ... just that now the namespace being complained about is different:

```
Uncaught Error:
  Element [{http://localhost:8000/ListMatchingProductsResponse.xsd}ListMatchingProductsResponse]
  could not be unmarshalled as is not known in this context
  and the property does not allow DOM content.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

I see at least a few problems.

First, I don't see element declarations in your schema. You're trying to unmarshal 
`ListMatchingProductsResponse` with the `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01` namespace, but where is it declared in [your schema](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-listmatchingproductsresponse-xsd)?

Next, your schema [has `http://localhost:8000/ListMatchingProductsResponse.xsd` as target namespace](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-listmatchingproductsresponse-xsd-L3). Your element has `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01` namespace. This is suspicious. I'm not saying it's wrong (since there are no global element declarations), but I guess you're mixing schema location and namespace URIs.

So as far as I can tell your schema is not complete and your XML does not match it. I might be wrong (I'd have to analyze all the imports to be sure), but I think you'll need to add global elements and check namespaces.

Comment: The `complexType` for `ListMatchingProductsResponse` is present but a element isn't. I'll try it out with changes. https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e#file-listmatchingproductsresponse-xsd-L38

+1 to your suggestion for 'add global elements and check namespaces' and I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as I know this was an xml issue and not a jsonix one all along. Thank you for your generous guidance.

Comment: don't want to leave any other readers hanging ... [revision 6](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/4f18c267a5eeb1f0f4ba9583f464f44e/revisions?diff=split#diff-b5652fd79c190f245a64938660620b67) of the gist has the fixes to schema based on @lexicore's recommendations